# How can I put my semicolon on same line on rich text box?

Tags: c#

```
using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand("myCommand", conn1))
{
     richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
     richTextBox1.AppendText(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() + ";");
     richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Result:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "XPKTBL_A" ON "TBL_A" ("FIELD_A1")
;
```

Expected result:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "XPKTBL_A" ON "TBL_A" ("FIELD_A1");
```

Comment: ever tried to trim the linebreak on the end of `crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString()`??

Comment: `richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("{0};",crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndreasNiedermair already suggested in comments but Trim line break should help

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString().TrimEnd('\r', '\n', ' ') + ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
string g = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() + ";";
richTextBox1.AppendText(g.Replace("\n", string.Empty));
```

Instead of

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() + ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment already, just adding it as an answer.

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("{0};",crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToStrin‌​g()));
```

Comment: I tried this but didnt work :(